# How do I set the canonical header to a HTTP response?

Tags: http, http-headers, canonical-link

I know that I can add a tag to the html head

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://geoffkenyon.com/how-to-add-canonical-tag-to-http-headers">
```

But I want to add this information in a HTTP response header instead. What header key and value would the above tag translate to?

I plan to do this in nginx as:

```
location /old-link {
    add_header key value;
}
```

Comment: Would this make more sense as a permanent redirect, in which case the canonical reference would be the `Location` header?

Comment: The old link needs to continue to be accessible. It is the same information in another format (pdf). So I don't want to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

This adds a header successfully. I haven't yet validated that google and others understand it.

```
location /docs-test/Otii_Tech_Spec.pdf {
    add_header Link '< href=https://geoffkenyon.com/how-to-add-canonical-tag-to-http-headers >; rel=\"canonical\"';
}
```

Comment: Google says so https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#rel-canonical-header-method